# Horizontal scroll is not working with jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

So I have a div contains unordered lists. what i need is when i click on the `right` span element the div should scroll towards **RIGHT**. But it is not happening.

```
<div id="hordiv">
   <ul>
     <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li><li>four</li><li>five</li>
   </ul> 
</div>
<span id="panLeft">Left</span> | <span id="panRight">Right</span>
```

Javascript code goes here

```
(function () {
    $("#panRight").click(function(){alert("hi");
    $("#hordiv").scrollLeft(90);
  });      
}());
```

fiddle link is attached [here](https://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/tfabo5xq/)

I dont know why it is not working. And i think may be it is because of some css releated issues. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are scrolling `$("#hordiv")` which is already 100% wide. 
You need to scroll the `ul` inside `hordiv` like

```
$("#hordiv>ul").scrollLeft(90);
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfabo5xq/1/)